# How can someone legally be a slave according to Sharia law?

Tags: sharia, islamic-basis, slavery

This thing has always confused me. If a muslim dude randomly walks up to me and says "Hey, man. Wanna be my slave?" and then I reply "Yeah. No problem bro.", does that legally make me his slave (by Islamic law)?

I'm not saying that I wanna be a slave (I don't), but if I did (for any weird reason), what would I have to do?

Comment: I'm sure the answer of your question is already covered on the site

Comment: So are there any hadith that mentions the circumstances under which slavery is legal? If not, then wouldn't that mean there are no restrictions to how one can become a slave? Because if that's the case, anyone can become a slave by will.

Comment: You -theoretically- can either be a war prisoner or a born slave in a Muslim household, but making a Muslim a slave is even haram. See http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/26399/13438 for some details and here for more http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/26402/13438

Comment: @Medi1Saif Could you give English references that muslims cannot be enslaved? The fatwa you link to [here](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12960/can-muslims-be-enslaved-by-other-muslims/26402#26402) is not available in English, unfortunately.

Comment: My last link includes the major source for that you don't need any fatwa.

Comment: And what about turning free non-muslims into slaves? If some Jewish guy agreed to be my slave (for any weird reason), would it be halal to make him my slave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of slave is:

> a person who is the legal property of another and is forced to obey them.

Taking a free person as a slave is not permissible in Islam. The prophet said:

> 'There are three categories of people against whom I shall myself be a
>   plaintiff on the Day of Judgement. **Of these three, one is he who
>   enslaves a free man,** then sells him and eats this money'.  Source: [al-Bukhari and Ibn Majjah](http://www.bbc.co.uk/religion/religions/islam/history/slavery_1.shtml)

In an Islamic State, a person can't legally be a slave of another person even if he wants to. Cause the other person doesn't have the right to force him to do things that are unacceptable in Islam.