How can Muslim women become slaves?
How can Muslim women become slaves?
I heard that it is allowed by Islam to have Muslim women as slaves. I feel this is not right at all, but I want to know for sure.
How could that happen?

To make it more clear, I'm not asking about non-Muslim slaves that become Muslims after being made slaves, or being born to slaves inheriting the slave status.
I am asking about free believing Muslim women becoming enslaved.

The options from the software are either to delete this question or to edit it.
But the software does not allow me to delete it, and editing it in a substantial way would make fool of all the answers and comments already given to the original, unchanged question.

Oooh, where have my comments gone?

All the comments.

Maybe someone knows that what I had written in the deleted comments was more than just a guess?

@UmH there are recurring questions on Muslim female slaves. From your link, this cannot happen. What am I missing?

You need to read it carefully, it CAN happen.

@UmH of course, it CAN happen, but lawfully? https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/12985/55518 says "Well it's haraam for Muslims to fight each other and take each others properties."

You are confusing two separate issues and both are addressed in the linked duplicate. It is allowed in Islam to have Muslim women as slaves but it is not allowed to enslave a free Muslim woman and turn her into a slave.

@UmH I only and deliberately asked about Muslim women to become slaves. Your comment makes it clear that it is not allowed for Muslims to enslave Muslim women (which holds also to Muslim men, right?)

@UmH in the now deleted comments, I also asked if Muslim slaves could be purchased from non-Muslim enslavers.

If the non-Muslims are Dhimmis then they are not permitted to capture Muslims, and if their non-Muslim slaves accept Islam they are forced to sell them to Muslim owners. If they are Harbis then their ownership over the Muslims is not correct and it is obligatory on the Muslims to free the prisoners by whatever means such as war or helping them to escape or paying their ransom. Purchasing is permissible but it would not make the Muslims own those Muslim slaves rather they would be freed.

You should ask one focused question per post. Comments are not for asking tangential questions.

@Umh you said (cited just to reference your very informative comment) " If the non-Muslims are Dhimmis ..." and I think there is as least as good as the already accepted answer. Thanks a lot.
